# Unnumbered section in article class

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am trying to include an "Acknowledgments" section in my thesis, I want this to be before the abstract and also not numbered. It doesn't need to appear in the ToC. I'm using the `article` class and read the

```
\section*{}
```

should do the trick. Sadly, it doesn't. The section is still numbered and appears in the ToC ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, final]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}

\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=20mm,top=32mm,bottom=26mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\changefont{12pt}{ptm}{m}{sl}\leftmark}
\rhead{\changefont{12pt}{ptm}{m}{sl}\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\linespread{1.08}
\captionsetup{labelsep=none, figurename= , tablename= }
\allsectionsfont{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\subsubsectionfont{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\newcommand{\changefont}[4]{\fontsize{#1}{#1}\fontfamily{#2} \fontseries{#3} \fontshape{#4} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\standard}{\changefont{12pt}{ptm}{m}{n}}
\newcommand{\fussnote}[1]{\footnote{\it #1}}
\newcommand{\abbildung}{\changefont{10pt}{ptm}{m}{it}}
\let\origitemize\itemize
\def\itemize{\origitemize\itemsep0pt}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} 
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table:} 
\parindent=0pt 
\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.6 } 

%Start of the actual document
\begin{document}

\author{Me}
\title{My Verry Interesting Project}
\date{\today}
\addtocounter{page}{-1}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{Letter}
\newpage
\input{Acknowledgments}
\newpage
\input{Abstract}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

In the `Acknowledgments.tex` file all I use is

```
\Section*{Acknowledgments}
```

Comment: I've replaced `\input{Acknowledgments}` with `\section*{Acknowledgments}` and it works. A nonnumbered Acknowledgments appears before the abstract, TOC, ... In any case, your code is not minimal and not compilable, I've added `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just to be sure, your Acknowledgment file should contain `\section*` and not `\Section*`.

Comment: create a minimal example file! It is not important for your problem that you use fancyhdr, the reason why you can delete such lines, and so on. At the end you'll have a _short_ source file which shows your problem

Comment: If your document said `\section{Acknowledgements}` and you changed it to `\section*{Acknowledgements}`, it will take two runs of latex before it disappears from the table of contents. Its number (in the text, not the contents) should disappear immediately.

Comment: just a passing thought: is the codes case sensitive? I mean \Section and \section are different?

Comment: @Anil Yes, LaTeX is case sensitive. **Most** of the commands you use are **lowercase**, few of them are not, for example the font size commands: `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge`, `\Huge` are different from each other.